# Axios not posting to Node.js app on Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, axios, contact-form

I'm working on my contact page for my static website, and normally, it'd post an email message to by Node.js app on Heroku and send me an email. However, Axios isn't posting the email, because I'm not seeing it on the console logs in Heroku.

Right now, I have a domain name, **mydomainname.com**, linked to my static website on Firebase, while **api.mydomainname.com**, is linked to my Heroku app.

I changed the Axios.post between `'/api/email'`, `'api.mydomainname.com/api/email'`, and `'mydomainname.com/api/email'`, but neither seemed to work. I thought that because my Heroku app and static website are linked to the same domain name, it'd work.

What would I configure Axios.post to?

Here's what I have at the moment:

#### Relevant Code

**ContactPage.js**

```
    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (this.validate()) {
            this.setState({
                disabled: true,
                emailSent: null
            });
            Axios.post('api.mydomainname.com/api/email', this.state)
                .then(res => {
                    if(res.data.success) {
                        this.setState({
                            emailSent: true
                        });
                        this.clearForm();
                    } else {
                        this.setState({
                            disabled: false,
                            emailSent: false
                        });
                    }
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                    this.setState({
                        disabled: false,
                        emailSent: false
                    });
                })
        }
    }
```

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express'); //Needed to launch server.
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors'); //Needed to disable sendgrid security.
const sendGrid = require('@sendgrid/mail'); //Access SendGrid library to send emails.
sendGrid.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
const app = express(); //Alias from the express function.

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(cors());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); // Change later to only allow our server
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
    next();
});

app.get('/api', (req, res, next) => {
    res.send('API Status: Running');
});

app.post('/api/email', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    const msg = {
        to: 'my@email.com',
        from: req.body.email,
        subject: req.body.subject,
        text: req.body.message
    }
    sendGrid.send(msg)
        .then(result => {
            res.status(200).json({
                success: true
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('error: ', err);
            res.status(401).json({
                success: false
            });
        });
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 4000);
```

[image: Console]

This is my console for my static website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found out that the connection to api.mydomainname.com was not secure and needed an SSL certificate. So, I registered my domain to Cloudflare.